# Conv3d prediction throws error Input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 1 vs 3

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to CNN .I am attempting gesture recognition. 3 images from beginning middle and end images are used in conv3d.
model is trained, i am loading the saved model and trying to predict.
following is the code.

```
img_idx=[0,14,29]  # sequence of images to use in a video 
n_timesteps = len(img_idx)
# load weights
model1 = Sequential()
#conv3d 1
model1.add(Conv3D(24, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', 
                 input_shape=(120, 160, 3, 3),
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
                 bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                 activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))
model1.add(LeakyReLU())
model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
#conv3d 2
model1.add(Conv3D(24, (3, 3, 3), padding='same',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),
                 activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)
                 ))
model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
model1.add(LeakyReLU())

#MaxPooling3D 1
model1.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))

model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(30))  #, kernel_initializer='he_uniform')
model1.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
model1.add(Dense(out_class, activation='softmax'))

model1.load_weights("/model-00004-0.81386-0.81297-0.91821-0.83000.h5")
print(model1.inputs)
x=next(train_generator)

print(x[0].shape)
tgt=x[0][0,:,:,:,:]
print(tgt.shape)
tgt = tgt[np.newaxis,:,:,:,:]
print(tgt.shape)
model1.predict(tf.transpose(tgt),steps=1)
```

*Out is obtained as*

```
[<tf.Tensor 'conv3d_11_input:0' shape=(None, 120, 160, 3, 3) dtype=float32>]
(10, 120, 160, 3, 3)
(120, 160, 3, 3)
(1, 120, 160, 3, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-57e6204980ae> in <module>()
     40 tgt = tgt[np.newaxis,:,:,:,:]
     41 print(tgt.shape)
---> 42 model1.predict(tf.transpose(tgt),steps=1)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 1 vs 3
     [[node conv3d_11/convolution (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1700]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Could you please help me resolve the exception.

The execution platform is google colab

- Keras==2.3.1
- Keras-Applications==1.0.8
- Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
- matplotlib==3.2.2
- numpy==1.18.5
- pandas==1.0.5
- scikit-image==0.16.2
- scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
- scipy==1.4.1
- tensorboard==2.2.2
- tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3
- tensorboardcolab==0.0.22
- tensorflow==2.2.0
- tensorflow-addons==0.8.3
- tensorflow-datasets==2.1.0
- tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
- tensorflow-gcs-config==2.2.0
- tensorflow-hub==0.8.0
- tensorflow-metadata==0.22.2
- tensorflow-privacy==0.2.2
- tensorflow-probability==0.10.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes with your `tf.tranpose(tgt)` inside your `mode.predict()`. I am not quite sure why you are transposing in the first place as `tgt` is already in the correct shape for your model. If you are trying to switch the last two dimensions, then you must specify the order of the dimensions in `tf.transpose()`. For example,

```
tgt = tf.transpose(tgt, (0, 1, 2, 4, 3))
# tgt.shape == (1, 120, 160, 3, 3)
```

Now, the last two dimensions are swapped.

Comment: Thanks for the response.this seems to be giving the same problem.. the original also fails

Comment: it will help if you could explain me what could be the issue

Comment: this worked fine with validation ahist = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, 
                    callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=val_generator, 
                    validation_steps=validation_steps, class_weight=None, workers=1, initial_epoch=0)

Comment: this is still open any help will be appreciated